# mqtt connection establishment between different systems using paho-mqtt-python :

Tags: python, mqtt

I used the following code and I get this error :

```
Time out error : [WinError 10060] A connection attempt  failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host failed to respond.
```

I also turned off the firewall in the systems i am using , still i get that error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# This is the Publisher

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("10.12.114.103",1883,60)
client.publish("topic/test", "Hello world!");
client.disconnect();
```

Comment: The MQTT broker @ 10.12.114.103:1883 is not answering, try connecting with MQTTfx or similar tool to check that the broker is working

Comment: I used hivemq broker, still getting the same error..

Comment: Are you sure the broker is running on 10.12.114.103 at the time you ran the test?

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably isn't with your python code as I tried a slightly modified version with hivemq's public test server and it worked fine. Here is the version I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# This is the Publisher

def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print(level, buf)

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_log = on_log
client.connect("broker.hivemq.com",1883,60)
client.publish("topic/test", "Hello world!");
client.disconnect();
```

Note that I modified it to return the log output which would be useful in debugging this. The script returned:

```
16 Sending PUBLISH (dFalse, q0, r0, m1, 'topic/test', ... (12 bytes)
```

Which is what I would expect from a successful connection. I also checked your code with the mosquitto test server and it worked fine.

It looks like your broker is not accepting your connection attempt. If you tried a public test server and it still didn't work then it suggests that something is interfering with your traffic on port 1883.

I think this is a broker issue, however, I did notice that you are not using any of the network loop functions (like client.loop_start) which, according to the paho documentation, may cause unpredictable behavior. You could try adding a loop like this to see if that helps

```
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_log = on_log
client.connect("broker.hivemq.com",1883,60)
client.loop_start
client.publish("topic/test", "Hello world!");
client.disconnect();
client.loop_stop
```

Comment: I get a Connection Refused error-"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Comment: My understanding of that error is that the broker simply isn't accepting the connection. Did you try the example code with one of the test brokers? Did it work?

Comment: I tried with "broker.hivemq.com" for which  i get the above error. But if I connect with a broker in the same local host it is getting connected..

Comment: Thanks a lot ... Its works now,  when i connect to hivemq broker or things.ubidots.com..... BUT I am not able to connnect to another laptop which has mosquitto broker running in it..... i get this socket.error errno 10060...

Comment: Good! Glad to that the code helped. (Feel free to mark the question as answered if you feel like it is dealt with.) Do you have the on_log callback defined? Is it giving you any useful output? 10060 basically means that the connection is being refused by the broker. Can you reach the laptop using mosquitto from the command-line? If you can't you might want to open a new question about broker configuration.